# Unable to render React function using ReactDOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write tests for the rendering function `Game()`, which is for a Connect 4 react page.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

import * as useGame from "./hooks/use-game";
import Game from ".";

const STATE_SPY = jest.spyOn(useGame, "default");
STATE_SPY.mockReturnValue({
  winner: "",
  dimensions: {
    numRows: 4,
    numCols: 4,
  },
  squares: [
    ["", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", ""],
  ],
});
const { container } = render(<Game />, document.getElementById("game"));
```

When I run the tests with `npm test`, I get `Target container is not a DOM element.`

If I create an element around the error I get a different error:

`const { container } = render(<Game />, document.createElement("div"));`

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'container' of '(0 , _reactDom.render)(...)' as it is null.`

Any idea how I need to write this `render()` function properly? I've searched all over the Internet, but it seems that I have set this up in a pretty standard way.

Here's the code being tested:

```
import React from "react";

import { useGame } from "./hooks";
import { Board, Settings } from "./components";
import { DARK_SYMBOL, LIGHT_SYMBOL, UseStyles } from "styles/styles";
import { dimensionsFormInput } from "types/form-inputs";

const INIT_ROW = 6;
const INIT_COL = 7;

// Game keeps track of the active player and winners of the Connect Four game
export default function Game(): JSX.Element {
  const {
    dimensions,
    setDimensions,
    squares,
    darkIsNext,
    winner,
    handleSquareClick,
  } = useGame(INIT_ROW, INIT_COL);
  const classes = UseStyles();

  return (
    <div id="game">
      <Board
        squares={squares}
        onClick={(row: number, col: number) => handleSquareClick(row, col)}
        winner={winner}
      />
      <span className={classes.blueText}>
        {winner.length > 0
          ? "Winner is " + winner
          : "Next piece: ".concat(darkIsNext ? DARK_SYMBOL : LIGHT_SYMBOL)}
      </span>
      <Settings
        dimensions={dimensions}
        onSubmit={(data: dimensionsFormInput) => setDimensions(data)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `render` from ReactDOM, I used `render` from 1@testing-library/react`. This allows me to conduct the tests I want to.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to create your own render function?, something like this, adapting the function to your needs, and use it in your test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
import ConnectedRouter from 'react-router-redux/ConnectedRouter';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReduxConnectedIntlProvider from '../ReduxConnectedIntlProvider';
import ThemeContext from '../context/theme-context';
import { store } from '../store';
import theme from '../theme/theme';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

const render = (
  ui,
  {
    route = '/',
    history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: [route] }),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) => {
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ReduxConnectedIntlProvider>
          <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>{children}</ConnectedRouter>
          </ThemeContext.Provider>
        </ReduxConnectedIntlProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  };
  return { ...rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }), history };
};

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';

// override render method
export { render };
```

The code for the ReduxConnectedIntlProvider:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { language, messages } = state.intl;
  return { locale: language, key: language, messages };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(IntlProvider);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This import is correct? `import Game from "."` i think that the correct is: `import Game from "./"`

Comment: It's correct. I also have an `index.tsx` in the same folder as game.tsx with `export { default } from "./game";`

Just to be safe, I tried your import method and received the same result.